# Best option for closing a question, using "close" button or "flag" button

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close

Now I have enough reputation to vote for close a question if required. So I found there are two ways to close them. First is by clicking in the **close** button and choose option which is relevant...And second is by clicking the **flag** button and then select the option **should be closed...** and then relevant reason...

So my question is what is difference between these two procedure or are they just same and how they affect my total close count and flag count?

Comment: When you go for flagging a question for close and if you didn't spent all your close votes then flag dialog will convert to close vote dialog.

Answer (score 7):

Those two options are exactly the same.

Going through the flagging options and selecting "should be closed" will redirect to the close voting dialog. You can verify this by seeing that the counter at the bottom changes from the amount of daily flags you have to the number of close votes you have.

Comment: [What is the difference between Flagging to Close and Voting to Close?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309662/608639) on Stack Overflow seems to indicate a *Flag* closes and sends the question into a low quality queue. Is Stack Overflow different than other sites in the Stack Exchange network? Or is the Stack Overflow answer wrong? Or something else?

Comment: @jww On Stack Overflow only, flags to close cause the question to go to Triage if it hasn't already been there. If it's already been there or if it's any other site, they go to the Close Votes queue.